# ReactJS - How do I render the component that is at the same level?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have few components and the design is like this:

[image]

[image]

How do I render/re-render the EmployeeTable Component (on the right) when I submit the form?  Cuz currently, when I onSubmit the form, it will call the "handleSubmit" function which updates the "submit" state, which in turn renders the EmpTable component under the form.  This is not what I want though; what I want is to render the same component (i.e. EmployeeTable) on the right with the new data I submitted.

**EmpForm.jsx**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import DepartmentComponent from "./Department";
import EmployeeTableComponent from "./EmpTable";
import TechnologyComponent from "./Technology";

let EmpFormComponent = () => {
  const [newEmployee, setNewEmployee] = useState({
    userId: "",
    userFirstName: "",
    userLastName: "",
    userDate: "",
    userDepartment: "",
    userTechnology: [],
    userCount: "",
  });
  const [submit, setSubmit] = useState(false);

  const updateChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.name !== "userTechnology") {
      setNewEmployee({ ...newEmployee, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    } else {
      // update userTechnology array list
      if (!newEmployee.userTechnology.includes(e.target.value)) {
        setNewEmployee({
          ...newEmployee,
          [e.target.name]: [...newEmployee.userTechnology, e.target.value],
        });
      } else {
        let filterUserTech = newEmployee.userTechnology.filter((item) => {
          return item !== e.target.value;
        });

        setNewEmployee({ ...newEmployee, [e.target.name]: filterUserTech });
      }
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSubmit(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="card ms-2">
      <div className="card-header">
        {" "}
        <h3>Employee Form</h3>
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="card-body">
          <div className="row g-1 my-1">
            {" "}
            <div className="col-md-2">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control text-center"
                placeholder="id"
                name="userId"
                onChange={updateChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-5">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control text-center"
                placeholder="first name"
                name="userFirstName"
                onChange={updateChange}
              />{" "}
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-5">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control text-center"
                placeholder="last name"
                name="userLastName"
                onChange={updateChange}
              />{" "}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row g-1 my-1">
            {" "}
            <div className="col-md-6">
              <input
                type="date"
                className="form-control"
                name="userDate"
                onChange={updateChange}
              />{" "}
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6">
              <DepartmentComponent updateChange={updateChange} />{" "}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row g-1 my-1">
            {" "}
            <div className="col-md-12">
              <p className="my-1 text-center">Select Technology</p>
              <TechnologyComponent updateChange={updateChange} />{" "}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row g-1 my-1">
            {" "}
            <div className="col-md-6">
              <p className="my-1 ms-1">Count of Completed Projects</p>{" "}
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control text-center"
                placeholder="count"
                name="userCount"
                onChange={updateChange}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row g-1 my-1">
            <div className="col-md-12">
              <button
                className="btn btn-outline-primary float-end"
                onClick={console.log(newEmployee)}
              >
                Submit
              </button>{" "}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      {submit && (
        <EmployeeTableComponent newEmployee={newEmployee} submit={submit} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
export default EmpFormComponent;
```

**EmpTable.jsx**

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faEye } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import EmpDetails from "./EmpDetails";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

let EmployeeTableComponent = ({ newEmployee, submit }) => {
  const [hideThisDetail, setHideThisDetail] = useState();

  const toggleUnhide = (key) => {
    setHideThisDetail(key);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(newEmployee);
  }, [submit]);

  let employees = [
    {
      id: 1,
      firstname: "Smith",
      lastname: "Mathew",
      joindate: "09/Jan/2021",
      department: "Development",
      technologies: [
        { id: 1, domain: "Java Spring Boot" },
        { id: 4, domain: " Asp.Net MVC" },
      ],
      projects: 3,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      firstname: "Maria",
      lastname: "Garcia",
      joindate: "09/Oct/2019",
      department: "Development",
      technologies: [
        { id: 1, domain: "Java Spring Boot" },
        { id: 2, domain: "Python Django" },
      ],
      projects: 8,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      firstname: "Jacob",
      lastname: "Abraham",
      joindate: "21/Mar/2021",
      department: "Testing",
      technologies: [{ id: 3, domain: "Express Js" }],
      projects: 1,
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      firstname: "Jessica",
      lastname: "Antoine",
      joindate: "18/Aug/2021",
      department: "Development",
      technologies: [
        { id: 1, domain: "Java Spring Boot" },
        { id: 4, domain: "Asp.Net MVC" },
      ],
      projects: 11,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <table className="table table-hover" id="myTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Employee</th>
          <th>Join Date</th>
          <th>Projects</th>
          <th>#</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {" "}
        {employees.map((item, key) => (
          /* Write here code to generate table view as given in the screenshot */
          <tr>
            <td>{item.id}</td>
            <td>
              {item.firstname}&nbsp;{item.lastname}
            </td>
            <td>{item.joindate}</td>
            <td>{item.projects}</td>
            <td>
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  toggleUnhide(key);
                }}
              >
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEye} color="#1c8ee3" />
              </button>
              {key === hideThisDetail && (
                <EmpDetails
                  key={key}
                  department={item.department}
                  technologies={item.technologies}
                />
              )}
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

export default EmployeeTableComponent;
```

Comment: you should elevate the employee state to your (root) Employee component and pass it down as props

Comment: @Krismu I tried it...``` <form onSubmit={() => <EmployeeTableComponent data={newEmployee} />}>``` but nothing happens once I hit Submit button